# CSS width transition choppy in FireFox if element rotated

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Try to animate width of element with text which was rotated.

Animation looks smoothly in Chrome, IE-11, Safari but choppy in FireFox.

How to make vertical div width animation more smoothly and clean?

SNIPPET

```js
function animate() {
  var e = document.getElementById('rotbox1');
 if (e.style.width == '120px') e.style.width = '200px'; else e.style.width = '120px';
  e = document.getElementById('rotbox2');
 if (e.style.width == '120px') e.style.width = '200px'; else e.style.width = '120px';
}

animate();

setInterval(animate, 2000);
```

```css
.wrp-v {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 20%;
  height: 40px;
}
.wrp-h {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 20%;
  height: 40px;
}
.rotbox {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2.0s ease;
  transition: width 2.0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp-v">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox1">Hello world</div>
</div>

<div class="wrp-h">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox2">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a known bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176

Comment: can always use jQuery animate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) instead `transform` :

```js
function animate() {
  var e = document.getElementById('rotbox1');
  if (e.style.height == '120px') e.style.height = '200px';
  else e.style.height = '120px';
  e = document.getElementById('rotbox2');
  if (e.style.width == '120px') e.style.width = '200px';
  else e.style.width = '120px';
}

animate();

setInterval(animate, 2000);
```

```css
.wrp-v {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  /* old Win safari */
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  direction: ltr;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 30%;
}
.wrp-h {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 20%;
}
.rotbox {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2.0s ease;
  transition: width 2.0s ease;
}
#rotbox1 {
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: height 2.0s ease;
  transition: height 2.0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp-v">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox1">Hello world</div>
</div>

<div class="wrp-h">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox2">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

changing `rotate(90deg);` to `rotate(90.3deg);` makes is appear smoother

read this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27898708/3049893

Comment: Div a little better, but text more chopply

Answer (score 0):

Making the container fixed width seems to solve the problem

```js
function animate() {
  var e = document.getElementById('rotbox1');
 if (e.style.width == '120px') e.style.width = '200px'; else e.style.width = '120px';
  e = document.getElementById('rotbox2');
 if (e.style.width == '120px') e.style.width = '200px'; else e.style.width = '120px';
}

animate();

setInterval(animate, 2000);
```

```css
.wrp-v {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;   /* new */
}

#rotbox1 {   /* new */
    position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
.wrp-h {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 20%;
  height: 40px;
}
.rotbox {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2.0s ease;
  transition: width 2.0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp-v">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox1">Hello world</div>
</div>

<div class="wrp-h">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox2">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `.rotbox` to `position: absolute;` fixes this issue. I have no idea why though. :)

```js
function animate() {
  var e = document.getElementById('rotbox1');
 if (e.style.width == '120px') e.style.width = '200px'; else e.style.width = '120px';
}

animate();

setInterval(animate, 2000);
```

```css
.wrp-v {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  height: 40px;
}

.rotbox {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2.0s ease;
  transition: width 2.0s ease;
  
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp-v">
  <div class="rotbox" id="rotbox1">Hello world</div>
</div>
```